While loops, uncomon problems with lists
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float

Create Starting Index = 0
Create an Ending Index = 4 in my case used int, then input...
Created an empty list, to be filled later on. My_Numbers
opened a loop using while Starting Index < Ending Index :
Created one variable called N, that N correspond to the float or integer numbers that will complete the list.
For the empty list on 3 ( My_Numbers = [ ] ) I append variable N.
In order proceed with the loop to the next index, I declare that Starting Index = Starting Index + 1.
As final result I intended to print each variable N, one by one whether inside that loop or in another new loop in sequence.

Would be similar to using for in loop. Where you ask for the variables, append it one by one into one list and if desired you can spit each variable one by one in the same loop or in a brand new loop.

would be similar to using for in loop as shown bellow:
Total_de_Notas = int(input(' Declare your list index extension: '))
My_Numbers = [ ]
for nota in range (0,Total_de_Notas,1) :
nota = float(input(' Declare your numbers: '))
My_Numbers.append(N)
print(' Printo todo o loop de notas lançadas: ',My_Numbers)
for nota in range (0,Total_de_Notas,1) :
print(Minhas_Notas[nota])

Rafael, This code in the comment section is unclear and hard to read. Can you update it in your question in appropriate step or so?

You are attempting to index the list using a float value N:
while (index_Inicial < index_Final) :
    print(Meus_Números[N])    
    index_Inicial = index_Inicial + 1

Instead of using N you should be using index_Inicial to access the list.
index = 0
while index < len(Meus_Números):
    print(Meus_Números[index])
    index += 1

